# Using createPage() twice for the same phantom instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to set up mocha tests with PhantomJS and I've encountered a problem where I can't use the same phantom instance to create multiple pages. The first test case runs just fine, but the second one times-out. I'd like to use just one instance, because it should be faster.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var phantom = require('phantom');
var path = require('path');

var ph;

describe('document', function() {
    before(function(done) { // Create only one phantom instance for the whole suite
        this.timeout(10000); // Prevent test case from aborting while phantom loads
        phantom.create(function(p) {
            ph = p;
            done();
        }, {
            dnodeOpts: {weak: false}
        });
    });

    it('should have a title', function(done) {
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            var url = 'file:///' + path.resolve(__dirname + '/index.html');
            page.open(url, function(status) {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.title;
                }, function(title) {
                    assert.equal('This is a title', title);
                    ph.exit();
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    });

    it('should have the same title', function(done) {
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            var url = 'file:///' + path.resolve(__dirname + '/index.html');
            page.open(url, function(status) {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.title;
                }, function(title) {
                    assert.equal('This is a title', title);
                    ph.exit();
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Why won't it open the page the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exiting PhantomJS after the first test, so the second test fails. You need to run `ph.exit();` only once after all the tests. I suspect that this can be done with:

```
describe('document', function() {
  before(...);
  after(function(done) {
    ph.exit();
    done();
  });
  it(...);
  it(...);
});
```

You can probably go so far as to `createPage` during `before` and use the `page` instance in the tests. Each test case should still open a new URL so that a fresh DOM is presented. This will probably be faster and more resilient against memory leaks.

By the way, PhantomJS' `localStorage` is never cleared (because it is stored on disk), so you have to clear it yourself after each test case or at the end of the execution.
PhantomJS also has only one CookieJar per process (which is only in memory), so you would have to remove the cookies if you test login or something like that.

Comment: The test cases will modify the DOM, so I should make the cases independent of execution order and reload the page each time.

Comment: No, you would just manage the `page` instance globally. Each `it` would still have to open the url anew. Btw, PhantomJS' localStorage is never cleared, so you have to clear it yourself after each test case or at the end of the execution. PhantomJS also has only one CookieJar per process, so would have to remove cookies if you test login or something like that.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that.